# SQL Server : get date ranges from daily repeating values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server, I have a table which has currency exchange rates stored as daily records in a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `crt` 
(
    `cur_code_fm` char(3) NOT NULL,
    `cur_code_to` char(3) NOT NULL,
    `crt_date` date NOT NULL,
    `crt_rate` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
    `ct_md` char(1) NOT NULL
);
```

The exchange usually remains the same over the span of several weeks and even months.

[Record sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqLrY.png)

```
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-24', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-25', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-26', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-27', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-28', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-29', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-30', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-31', '550.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-01', '565.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-02', '565.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-03', '565.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-04', '565.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-05', '565.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-06', '565.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-07', '565.00000000', 'M'
'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-08', '565.00000000', 'M'
```

I would like to consolidate this into date ranges like this:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUFUF.png)

```
'89', 'USD', 'CRC', '2013-12-01', '2013-12-31', '494.00000000', 'M'
'90', 'USD', 'CRC', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-31', '498.00000000', 'M'
'91', 'USD', 'CRC', '2014-02-01', '2014-02-28', '522.00000000', 'M'
'92', 'USD', 'CRC', '2014-03-01', '2014-03-31', '542.00000000', 'M'
'93', 'USD', 'CRC', '2014-04-01', '2014-04-30', '540.00000000', 'M'
'94', 'USD', 'CRC', '2014-05-01', '2014-06-30', '545.00000000', 'M'
'95', 'USD', 'CRC', '2014-07-01', '2014-07-31', '533.00000000', 'M'
'96', 'USD', 'CRC', '2014-08-01', '2014-12-31', '534.00000000', 'M'
'97', 'USD', 'CRC', '2016-01-01', '2017-06-30', '500.00000000', 'M'
'98', 'USD', 'CRC', '2017-07-01', '2017-12-31', '550.00000000', 'M'
'99', 'USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-01', '2018-06-30', '565.00000000', 'M'
'100', 'USD', 'EUR', '2010-01-01', '2010-05-31', '1.45000000', 'D'
'101', 'USD', 'EUR', '2013-07-01', '2013-07-31', '0.76400000', 'D'
'102', 'USD', 'SFR', '2010-01-01', '2010-06-30', '1.15000000', 'M'
'103', 'USD', 'SFR', '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', '1.01500000', 'M'
'104', 'USD', 'USD', '2004-01-01', '2029-12-31', '1.00000000', 'M'
```

In MySQL I can do this easily by using variables to track the rate and currency changes between records using:

```
SET @set := 0;
SET @pfm := '' Collate utf8_unicode_ci;
SET @pto := '' Collate utf8_unicode_ci;
SET @prt := 0;

SELECT
    grate.serie,
    grate.cur_code_fm AS Min_cur_code_fm,
    grate.cur_code_to,
    MIN(grate.crt_date) AS datefrom,
    MAX(grate.crt_date) AS dateto,
    grate.crt_rate,
    grate.ct_md
FROM
    (SELECT
         CASE
            WHEN (@pfm != snatch.crt.cur_code_fm) OR (@pto != snatch.crt.cur_code_to) OR (@prt != snatch.crt.crt_rate)
               THEN @set := @set + 1
               ELSE @set
         END AS serie,
         crt.cur_code_fm,
         crt.cur_code_to,
         crt.crt_date,
         crt.crt_rate,
         crt.ct_md,
         @pfm := crt.cur_code_fm,
         @pto := crt.cur_code_to,
         @prt := crt.crt_rate
     FROM
         crt
     ORDER BY
         crt.cur_code_fm, crt.cur_code_to, crt.crt_date) grate
GROUP BY
    grate.serie, grate.cur_code_fm,
    grate.cur_code_to, grate.crt_rate, grate.ct_md;
```

How can I achieve the same in SQL Server 2008+ ?

Thanks.

Solved it with [ZLK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5552667/zlk)'s comment:

```
SELECT
  grate.serie,
  grate.CUR_CODE_FM,
  grate.CUR_CODE_TO,
  Min(grate.CRT_DATE) AS Min_CRT_DATE,
  Max(grate.CRT_DATE) AS Max_CRT_DATE,
  grate.CRT_RATE,
  grate.CT_MD
FROM
  (SELECT
      serie = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY CRT.CUR_CODE_FM, CRT.CUR_CODE_TO,
      CRT.CT_MD ORDER BY CRT.CRT_DATE) - Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY
      CRT.CUR_CODE_FM, CRT.CUR_CODE_TO, CRT.CT_MD,
      CRT.CRT_RATE ORDER BY CRT.CRT_DATE),
      CRT.CUR_CODE_FM,
      CRT.CUR_CODE_TO,
      CRT.CRT_DATE,
      CRT.CRT_RATE,
      CRT.CT_MD
    FROM
      CRT) grate
GROUP BY
  grate.serie,
  grate.CUR_CODE_FM,
  grate.CUR_CODE_TO,
  grate.CRT_RATE,
  grate.CT_MD
ORDER BY
  grate.CUR_CODE_FM,
  grate.CUR_CODE_TO,
  Min_CRT_DATE
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sample input, expected output in text.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding what you're trying to do, this is a standard islands and gaps problem. There are a variety of ways to tackle this. One easy way is using a difference in row numbers... For example `serie = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cur_code_fm, cur_code_to, ct_md ORDER BY crt_date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cur_code_fm, cur_code_to, ct_md, crt_rate ORDER BY crt_date)` and then using that to group, assuming I'm understanding your question. If dates are unique (are they?) then the first row_number would just be `order by date` rather than partitioning...

Comment: This is dead on: serie = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cur_code_fm, cur_code_to, ct_md ORDER BY crt_date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cur_code_fm, cur_code_to, ct_md, crt_rate ORDER BY crt_date)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how did you come up with the rates on the expected results. but I think the rest I've got them. Here is something you could start with :

```
DECLARE 
    @crt TABLE (
      cur_code_fm char(3) NOT NULL,
      cur_code_to char(3) NOT NULL,
      crt_date date NOT NULL,
      crt_rate decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
      ct_md char(1) NOT NULL        
    )

INSERT INTO @crt VALUES 
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-24', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-25', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-26', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-27', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-28', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-29', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-30', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2017-12-31', 550.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-01', 565.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-02', 565.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-03', 565.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-04', 565.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-05', 565.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-06', 565.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-07', 565.00000000, 'M'),
('USD', 'CRC', '2018-01-08', 565.00000000, 'M')



SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY crt_date_fm) RN, *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        cur_code_fm
    ,   cur_code_to
    ,   crt_date_fm
    ,   crt_date_to
    ,   MAX(crt_rate) crt_rate
    ,   ct_md 
    ,   reaccuring
    FROM (
        SELECT
            cur_code_fm
        ,   cur_code_to
        ,   DATEADD(DAY, - DAY(crt_date) + 1 , crt_date) crt_date_fm
        ,   DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, - DAY(crt_date) + 1 , crt_date) ) ) crt_date_to
        ,   COUNT(cur_code_fm) OVER(PARTITION BY cur_code_fm, YEAR(crt_date), MONTH(crt_date)) recurring 
        ,   crt_rate
        ,   ct_md 
        FROM @crt
    ) D
    GROUP BY 
        cur_code_fm
    ,   cur_code_to
    ,   crt_date_fm
    ,   crt_date_to
    ,   ct_md 
    ,   reaccuring
) E
```

the recurring count the number of repeated rates in the same month.

If you could clarify your question, and explain what logic are you using on the rates, I'll probably update my answer to a full one.